# Chromium reserves space for rotated svg elements

Tags: html, css, svg, puppeteer, pdf-generation

I have a bare `<svg/>` element which is meant to be printed via a headless chrome/chromium.
The content of the `<svg/>` element is pretty complex and is build according to the landscape coordinates (width > height). Then the root `<svg/>` node is rotated by `270` degrees via `transform` attribute. Unfortunately, it is not known in advance whether the element will be rotated, so building it in a "portrait" (width < height) style is impossible.

Here's a small minimised example:

```html
<svg version="1.1" width="2175"  height="1575" transform="rotate(270) translate(-300 -300)"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <rect width="2175" height="1575" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

When you open this `svg` within Chrome and scroll to the right edge you see an extra white space which is page/document's background:
[image]

(without the `translate` there would be whitespaces around the rectangle)

During some triangulation I've found that the behaviour changed starting from Chromium 108. Previously, browser's page fitted the rotated `svg`.

Here's a comparison with Firefox 122.0 which fits the `svg` and interprets it as a "portrait"-oriented.
[image]

Firefox (and chrome < 108) doesn't have this extra space:
[image]

Is it possible to **get rid of this extra white space** when using Chrome/Chromium-based browsers?
While the `svg` is opened as it is - it's not possible to tweak it via javascript, so I need a svg/inline css solution.

P.S. We are upgrading a very old puppeteer which comes with Chromium 78 to the latest versions which comes with Chromium (Chrome for testing) 120+. Chrome upgrade led to the above problem.

P.P.S I'm printing the whole page, so I can't add `style="background:red;"` to the parent `<svg/>` to hide the problem.

Comment: you can report Chrome bugs to their [bugtracker](https://issues.chromium.org/issues)

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a bug or a "new reality" / silly me, cause it persists in 13 major versions.